# c++ compile error under android cmake

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm using android studio to compile c++ code and my ndk version is android-ndk-r12b. In my project I  defined two functions in mp4muxer.h:

```
void Engine_create(const char *file, uint32_t flag);

void Engine_readFile(const char *file);
```

and implemented in mp4muxer.cpp like this:

```
void Engine_readFile(const char *file, uint32_t flag) {


    MP4FileHandle handle = MP4Read(file);
    if (handle == MP4_INVALID_FILE_HANDLE) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, TAG, "Create mp4 file failed invalid handle!");
        return;
    }
    MP4TrackId trackId = MP4FindTrackId(handle, 0, MP4_TEXT_TRACK_TYPE, 0);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, TAG, "Read trackId: %d", trackId);
    if (trackId == MP4_INVALID_TRACK_ID) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, TAG, "Create mp4 file using mp4v2 library! invalid trackId: %d", trackId);
        return;
    }

    uint32_t count;
    uint8_t* data = (uint8_t * ) malloc((size_t)(10 * sizeof(uint8_t)));
    uint32_t sid = 1;
    while (MP4ReadSample(handle, trackId, sid++, &data, &count)) {

       int i;
       for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, TAG, "value: %d", data[i]);
       }

    }

    MP4Close(handle);
}

void Engine_create(const char* file) {

    MP4FileHandle handle = MP4Create(file);
    if (handle == MP4_INVALID_FILE_HANDLE) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, TAG, "Create mp4 file failed invalid handle!");
        return;
    }
    MP4TrackId trackId = MP4AddTextTrack(handle, 3);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, TAG, "Create trackId: %d", trackId);
    if (trackId == MP4_INVALID_TRACK_ID) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, TAG, "Create mp4 file using mp4v2 library! invalid trackId: %d", trackId);
        return;
    }

    uint32_t count = 50;
    uint8_t data[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    while (count-- > 0) {

        MP4WriteSample(handle, trackId, data, 10);

    }

    MP4Close(handle);

}
```

and called the functions:

```
include <jni.h>

#include "../mp4muxer.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include "../muxing.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif





static void MuxerEngine_engine(JNIEnv *env, jobject clazz, jstring fileName) {

    jboolean isCopy;
//    const char * cstr = env->GetStringUTFChars(fileName, &isCopy);
    const char * cstr = NULL;
    Engine_create(cstr, 0);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(fileName, cstr);
}


static void MuxerEngine_read(JNIEnv *env, jobject clazz, jstring fileName) {

    jboolean isCopy;
    const char * cstr = env->GetStringUTFChars(fileName, &isCopy);
    Engine_readFile(cstr);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(fileName, cstr);
}
```

but when i compiled the compiler said:

> error: undefined reference to 'Engine_create(char const*, unsigned
>   int)' error: undefined reference to 'Engine_readFile(char const*)'

what confused me is: I defined the function: `Engine_create(const char*, unsigned int)` but got the error info:

> Engine_create(char const*, unsigned int) ,the parameter is 
>       const char *  but not 
>       char cont *

Comment: `const char *` and `char const*` means the same thing.

Comment: Does `Engine_create()` take one or two arguments? Your declaration and definition differ.

Comment: Same thing about `Engine_readFile`.

Comment: Did you declared those functions in muxing.h ? because probabelly your two functions are wrapped in an `extern "C" { }` block, I am right? if it is the case you must declare them in `muxing.h` as  you are including it as extern c header